# Avoiding loop in R function

Tags: r, performance, loops, vectorization

I'm writing an R package that uses the following code in one of its functions

#### Here I load the data

A link to the data is the following

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rrh4c1sn96ja7wp/PIBcol_SD.txt

```
   info   <-  read.table("./Datos/PIBcol_SD.txt",header=TRUE,row.names=1,dec=".")
   attach     (info)

   lpib      <-  ts   (log(PIB) , start= c(1982,1)  , frequency = 4)
   series     <-  diff (lpib     , lag=4)
   trans     <-  lag   (series    , k=-1)

   linear    <- c(1,4)
   nonlinear <- 1
```

#### Here is where the function starts

```
  linear <- c (0,linear)
  nonlinear <- c (0,nonlinear)

  linear_list           <- lapply (linear, function(i) lag(series, k=-i))
  linear_dat            <- na.omit(do.call(cbind, linear_list))
  colnames(linear_dat)  <- paste0 ("lag_",linear)

  nonlinear_list           <- lapply (nonlinear, function(i) lag(series, k=-i))
  nonlinear_dat            <- do.call(cbind, nonlinear_list)
  colnames(nonlinear_dat)  <- paste0 ("nl.lag_",nonlinear)  
  nonlinear_dat            <- window (nonlinear_dat, start=start(linear_dat),end=end(linear_dat))

  trans       <- window (trans, start=start(linear_dat),end=end(linear_dat))
  scale       <- sqrt   (var(trans))
  grid        <- list()


    for (c1 in seq(min(trans), max(trans), mean(trans)/20)){
      for (gamma in seq(1,100,0.5))                                    {

    transition  <- (1+exp(-(gamma/scale)*(trans-c1)))^-1

    lin_eq                <- paste0("lag_0 ~",  paste(paste(colnames(linear_dat)[-1]), sep="",collapse='+'))      
    nonlin_eq             <- paste0("transition + ",paste("I(transition*",paste(colnames(nonlinear_dat)[-1],")"), sep="",collapse='+'))

    grid.regre <-lm(paste0(lin_eq,"+",nonlin_eq),data=data.frame(linear_dat,nonlinear_dat,trans)) 

    coef  <- grid.regre$coefficients
    RSS   <- sum(grid.regre$residuals^2)
    grid[[length(grid)+1]] <- c(RSS,gamma,c1,coef)  
  } 
}

Small_RSS         <- which.min(sapply(grid, "[[", 1))  
Start_val         <- grid[[Small_RSS]]
names(Start_val)  <- c("RSS","gamma","c1",c("intercept",colnames(linear_dat)[-1],"nl_intercept",colnames(nonlinear_dat)[-1]))

Start_val
```

The iterations seem to take forever when I include some other parameters like c1. In a previous post someone told me that there was a way in which I could avoid doing the loop (perhaps using expand.grid). I have tried to do this unsuccessfully.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem here is likely that you are growing an object `grid` rather than that you're looping.  `for` loops are perfectly efficient on their own.  See circle 2 in [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).  Best solution might be to make it a matrix with 4 cols and replace into that after sizing it before you start your loop.

Comment: Would be nice to have a reproducible example here to play with. Maybe you have some example data you're bundling with your package?

Comment: That Inferno is some good stuff @BrodieG. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I see what you mean @BrodieG, I'll take a look.

Comment: I shared the data and a bigger part of the code @brandon-bertelsen

Comment: Running now. How long is "forever?" and it looks like you only use `info` once, specifically when you take `log(PIB)`. You should avoid using `attach` in general, but if you are just using one variable in your data once, it is completely unnecessary. Just use `log(info$PIB)`. And your loop is already finished on my computer. Why is this too slow?

Comment: Hi! @rawr it becomes slow when I add another parameter, say c2 with the same range as c1 with the form -(gamma/scale)*(trans-c1)*(trans-c2) in the transition equation